# Why does this parameter appear twice in this super().__init__() method?

Tags: python, inheritance, init, super

Why does `super().__init__(length, length)` has two **length** parameters in the Square class.

This code is from an article I'm reading trying to understand the super() function in Python. I would much appreciate some advice. Thanks in advance.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.length + 2 * self.width

# Here we declare that the Square class inherits from the Rectangle class
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        # This is the line that I don't understand.
        super().__init__(length, length)
```

Comment: The arguments to the super class are (length, width), so the super call will need two parameters. since a square has equal width and height, the length is passed in twice to the rectangle constructor

Comment: Thank you! Do I always need to fill the same number of parameters when I call a method through super()?